# Rendering a FormSet in Django

Tags: python, html, django

I want to create a `FormSet` which allows users to add forms as needed. However, when I render the page, I am receiving an error:

```
ValueError: The view website.views.presales didn't return an HttpResponse object.
  It returned None instead.
```

I would like to always render the form blank. Please let me know if any other information is needed, thanks!

Note: `cwObj.get_opportunities()` is an API call to create an object from a JSON response to populate the `select_opportunity` dropdown. Lastly, I am using AJAX to dynamically calculate the value of the span `Total` using `data-total-url="{% url 'presales_total' %}"`.

**forms.py**

```
class PresalesForm(forms.Form):
    class Meta:
        model = Presales
        fields = ('selected_opportunity', 'task_description', 'hours', 'selected_engineer_level', 'total_cost')
```

**views.py**

```
def presales(request):
    my_opportunities = cwObj.get_opportunities()

    PresalesFormSet = formset_factory(PresalesForm, extra=1)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        presales_formset = PresalesFormSet(request.POST)

        if presales_formset.is_valid():

            for presales_form in presales_formset:
                selected_opportunity = request.POST.get('selected_opportunity')
                task_description = request.POST.get('task_description')
                hours = request.POST.get('hours')
                select_engineer_level = request.POST.get('select_engineer_level')

            else:
                presales_formset = PresalesFormSet(initial="None")

                context = {'presales_formset': presales_formset, 'my_opportunities': my_opportunities}

            return render(request, 'website/presales.html', context)
```

**presales.html**

```
<form action="{% url 'presales' %}" method="post" name="presalesForm" id="presalesForm" data-total-url="{% url 'presales_total' %}">
                {% csrf_token %}

                {{ presales_formset.management_form }}

                {% for presales_form in presales_formset %}
                <div class="field">
                    <label class="label is-large">Create Task</label>
                </div>
                <div class="section">
                    <div class="field">
                        <label class="label">Opportunity</label>
                        <div class="select">
                            <select name="select_opportunity" id="select_opportunity">
                                <option value="">Opportunity</option>
                                {% for opportunity in my_opportunities %}
                                <option name="selected_opportunity" id="selected_opportunity" value="{{ opportunity.name }}">{{ opportunity.name }}</option>
                                {% endfor %}
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <label class="label">Task Description:</label>
                    <div class="field">
                        <div class="control">
                            <input class="input" name="task_description" id="task_description" placeholder="Task Description">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <label class="label">Hours</label>
                    <div class="field">
                        <div class="control">
                            <input class="input" name="hours" id="hours" placeholder="Hours">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <label class="label">Engineer Level:</label>
                    <div class="field">
                        <div class="select">
                            <select name="select_engineer_level" id="select_engineer_level">
                                <option value="">Engineer Level</option>
                                <option value="PM">PM</option>
                                <option value="Solutions Technician">Solutions Technician</option>
                                <option value="Solutions Engineer">Solutions Engineer</option>
                                <option value="Senior Solutions Engineer">Senior Solutions Engineer</option>
                                <option value="Solutions Architect">Solutions Architect</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="field">
                    <div class="control">
                        <button class="button is-info" type="button">Add Task</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                {% endfor %}
                <span class="label is-medium is-pulled-right" id="total_cost">Total: {{ total }}</span>
            </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your view does **NOT** return an `HttpResponse` in all cases, which is an error. This happend when `request.method` is different than POST and when the formset is not valid.

This is pretty easy to spot when removing most of the code and just leaving the conditional statements:

```
def presales(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if presales_formset.is_valid():
            ...
            return render(request, 'website/presales.html', context)
```

You have to return other `HttpResponse`'s in the other cases as well to solve this error.

For example, you could un-indent the line `return render(...` 2 levels, so that the view always returns the template.

Comment: Actually, it looks like it should be everything from `else` onwards that needs to be unindented two levels.